Хранение аватаров пользователей django docker nginx
Сейчас в своем django проекте, я храню аватары пользователей как media, в формате <session_id>.png. По задумке media должен раздавать nginx, но проблема в том, что nginx и django это разные docker контейнеры, и Nginx не может получить доступ к media в django
Каким образом можно достучаться до аватарок, получать их и раздавать?

Если они на одном жестком диске - прокинь волумку с медиа

@eri, огромное спасибо! Не думал о таком простом и красивом способе
